# Alternative of spring-cloud-starter-aws maven dependency for Using AWS SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml, amazon-sqs

For my project I will be using the `@SQSListener` annotation. I have added 2 maven dependencies in my springboot pom.xm:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-messaging</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I understand that we have to use the "spring-cloud-aws-messaging" maven dependency, but is there any alternative for the "spring-cloud-starter-aws" dependency? It adds dependencies which are not necessary. I just want to have dependencies related to AWS SQS. Please let me know if you have any solution to this.

Comment: `SQSListener` is already part of `spring-cloud-aws-messaging`, so what happens if you just remove the starter dependendency completely?

Comment: Then it won't listen to SQS. Tried that also.

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this